# GPUImage pause/resume playing not well

Tags: ios, video, playback, gpuimage

I cloned [this work](https://github.com/evfemist/GPUImage) of pause/resume recording of `GPUImage`, it works well, and I can play the `video on my mac` --- it works.

But I can't play the total movie on my iphone (seems the sound playing while the video is blocking),and when I use `NSDATA` from url, it only get the first part of the video.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK now I solved it.
It is because I didn't stop on the proper time and recording seems to be unfinished when I start to get the data from the url.
BTW, the work is awesome.